# Is it possible to prove this combinatorial?

Tags: combinatorics

Show that
$$\dbinom{n}{0} + \dbinom{n}{2} + \dbinom{n}{4} + \cdots + \dbinom{n}{2k} = 2^{n-1}$$
where $2k$ is the largest even integer not exceeding $n$.
Not sure how to prove this in a combinatorial proof. I need to prove that both sides are equal, but I've never seen a proof like this.

Comment: I think you can prove it by induction on $n$.

Comment: There's a very simple algebraic proof combining the binomial expansions of $(1-1)^n$ and $(1 + 1)^n$

Comment: The k should be edited out of the question.  A variable probably got switched or summation limits weren't spelled out clearly.  The sum should clearly go to $2 \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$.

Answer (score 2):

You want to prove that there are $2^{n-1}$ ways to select an even number of elements out of a set with $n$ elements. First pick a number of elements from the first $n-1$ elements; there are $2^{n-1}$ ways to do this. Each of these ways extends uniquely to a way of selecting an even number of elements from $n$ elements, by choosing the last element if we have an odd number of elements and by not choosing the last element if the number of elements we have is already even. In other words, there is a bijection between the even subsets of an $n$-element set and all the subsets of an $(n-1)$-element-set; as a result, in both cases there are $2^{n-1}$ such sets.

Answer (score 1):

Note that:
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{k\ge 0:2k\le n} {n\choose 2k}=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^n{n\choose k} +\sum\limits_{l=0}^{n} {n\choose j}(-1)^l\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left( 2^n+0\right)=2^{n-1}
\end{equation}

Comment: I am pretty certain OP asked for a combinatorial proof.